# SQL: Auto-reference table on update cascade

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table with a foreign key auto-referenced, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    ref INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE user
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ref) REFERENCES user(id)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then, I insert values in the table:

```
INSERT INTO user 
VALUES(1, "User1", NULL), (2, "User2", 1), (3, "User3", 1), (4, "User4", 3);

SELECT * FROM user;
```

And I update a user to check if, when I update the id of a user, then the FK is updated on cascade:

```
UPDATE user 
SET id = 5 
WHERE id = 1;
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ('prueba'.'user', CONSTRAINT 'user_ibfk1' FOREIGN KEY ('ref') REFERENCES 'user' ('id') ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Can anyone say me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do. It's a limitation of MySQL's foreign key implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the dev document.  Your self-referential "ON UPDATE CASCADE" acts like "ON UPDATE RESTRICT".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates. A self-referential ON DELETE SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON DELETE CASCADE. Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.